# Matrix multiplied by inverse does not yield Identity

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to find the inverse matrix of a given matrix using the `np.linalg.inv()` function. `inv` yields a matrix which looks alright, but then when trying to multiply the original matrix by inverse the output is not the identity as supposed by the inverse matrix definition.

```
from numpy.linalg import inv

M = np.random.random((4, 4))
Mi = inv(M)
I = M @ Mi # using matrix multiplication operator
I.astype(int) #as the output looks like 2.77555756e-17

>>> array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Which is clearly not the identity (gives a slightly different answer when running multiple times)

Comment: Integer truncation works like that. Did you try rounding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try rounding it first before converting to int.

```
np.around(I).astype(int)
```

Creating a random matrix:

```
>>> M = np.random.random((4,4))
>>> M
array([[0.51351957, 0.57864882, 0.0489495 , 0.85066216],
       [0.60052988, 0.93844708, 0.74651889, 0.17237584],
       [0.26191596, 0.46451226, 0.46514401, 0.81917544],
       [0.19247662, 0.82801899, 0.83839146, 0.08531949]])
```

Taking inverse:

```
>>> from numpy.linalg import inv
>>> Mi = inv(M)
>>> Mi
array([[-1.3515514 ,  3.53647196,  1.0391335 , -3.64654487],
       [ 2.76188122, -2.23981308, -2.74634579,  3.35680468],
       [-2.44320291,  1.47102487,  2.36135635, -1.28451339],
       [ 0.2533113 , -0.69591469,  1.10498293, -0.00818495]])
```

Now, multiplying `M` and `Mi` should produce identity.

```
>>> M @ Mi
array([[ 1.00000000e+00, -4.44089210e-16, -1.11022302e-16, -6.93889390e-18],
       [-4.16333634e-17,  1.00000000e+00, -8.32667268e-17, -8.60856525e-17],
       [ 5.55111512e-17, -2.22044605e-16,  1.00000000e+00, -1.57859836e-16],
       [ 6.24500451e-17, -8.32667268e-17, -2.35922393e-16, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

But this is clearly not identity. But if you look closely, the diagonal values are pretty close to 1, and all other values are really small numbers (almost zeros), like `-16` or `-17` in the exponent.

This error is, because float values are never the exact values, they always have some error in them. Have a look at the article [15. Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Now, if we just convert it to int, the chances are, that it will still not be an identity. Because a value which is really close to 1, it can actually be a little smaller than 1, resulting in 0 when casted to `int`.

```
>>> (M @ Mi).astype(int)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But if you round it first before converting to `int`, you'll get an identity.

```
>>> np.around(M @ Mi).astype(int)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 4):

When you print out `I`, it looks like this:

```
array([[ 1.00000000e+00, -5.55111512e-17, -1.66533454e-16, 0.00000000e+00],
       [ 6.38378239e-16,  1.00000000e+00, -5.55111512e-17, 0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [-5.55111512e-17, -1.11022302e-16, -1.24900090e-16, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

However, the `1.00` entries are not exact. When you print `1 - I`, you can see this:

```
array([[-2.22044605e-16,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  2.22044605e-16,  1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

The positive diagonal entries represent values in `I` that are slightly less than one. When you do integer truncation (which is what `astype(int)` does), you will set those elements to zero. Instead, [round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) the values to the nearest integer instead of truncating:

```
np.around(I).astype(int)
```

However, you will not always have integer inputs like this, in which case rounding will be misleading. Numpy provides the [`allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) funcion for comparing values within a tolerance:

```
np.allclose(I, np.identity(I.shape[0]), rtol=0, atol=1e-15)
```

You can also do an element-wise check using [`isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
np.isclose(I, np.identity(I.shape[0]), rtol=0, atol=1e-15)
```

I set the relative tolerance to zero since it is multiplied by the elements of the second matrix, making it useless in this situation.

Comment: This would still hide differences that are up to 50%.

Comment: Yes, that was bugging me, so I'm adding in a paragraph for that.

Comment: I think the `astype(int)` was just added to view the matrix.  The real usecase probably doesn't involve converting to `int`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher. I've completed my edits. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: No worries, nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `astype` function does not round, it simply truncates. So, the reason you do not see the identity matrix is that the other values that should be `1` were somewhere around `0.99999`. You can use this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((4,4))
b = np.linalg.inv(a)
# 0.00001 is the tolerance about which you which to consider values to be == 1
c = np.array(a@b + 0.00001, dtype=int)
print(c)
```

If you want to simply round (high tolerance == 0.5) use this instead:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((4,4))
b = np.linalg.inv(a)
c = np.array(np.round(a@b), dtype=int)
print(c)
```

Additionally, it is likely best practice to use the full `np.linalg.inv` function.

Comment: It's not the best solution, as a result that is 50% off would consider the result as good when it's not.

Comment: I have updated it -- the first solution includes a tolerance threshold

Comment: This is still far from correct and doesn't properly check that the result is close to the identity matrix. The proper way to do it is @MadPhysicist answer.

Comment: "correct" is subjective -- and my solution is significantly more readable than the @MadPhysicist answer, which also matters.

Comment: the author wanted to know how to get the identity, not check if it was the identity -- that is a different question

Comment: Yes, that's what he wanted, but used the wrong way to check for it: "when trying to multiply the original matrix by inverse the output is not the identity as supposed by the inverse matrix definition". Let's give good practices and the proper way of doing things.

Comment: understood -- while improve in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The question is, is the matrix close to `np.eye(4)` or not.

This is how you should check:

```
I = M@Mi
EPS = 1e-8
r = np.all(np.abs(I - np.eye(4)) < EPS)
```

`r` will indicate if the two matrices (`I` and the identity) are close up to 1e-8.

Comment: Your epsilon should be much smaller than that. +1 for being the first to post a reasonable comparison method.

Comment: Indeed, I just gave 1e-8 for reference, I would use the epsilon for a double or a small increment over it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal here?

It seems like you just want to know how to get the identity matrix and compare if the results of your matrix multiplication are close to it.

If so, this is what you should do:

```
import numpy as np

matrix1 = np.random.random((4,4))
matrix1_inv = np.linalg.inv(matrix1)

# get what may be identity matrix
ident_pred = matrix1 @ matrix1_inv

# get what is the identity matrix
ident_true = np.identity(matrix1.shape[0])

# check that they are the same
print(np.allclose(ident_pred, ident_true))
```

Comment: This is a rehash of the answer I posted three hours ago.